# Data not showing Recycler view with two ViewHolder from firestore

Tags: android, firebase, android-adapter, google-cloud-firestore

When I try to bind the data nothing shows in an emulator only the progress. But in the Logcat every thing is fine

My base `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`:

```
public abstract class FirestoreAdapter<VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VH> implements EventListener<QuerySnapshot> {

    private static final String TAG = "Firestore Adapter";


    private Query mQuery;
    private ListenerRegistration mRegistration;

    protected ArrayList<DocumentSnapshot> mSnapshots = new ArrayList<>();

    public FirestoreAdapter(Query query) {
        mQuery = query;
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
        if (e != null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "onEvent:error", e);
            onError(e);
            return;
        }

        // Dispatch the event
        Log.d(TAG, "onEvent:numChanges:" + documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges().size());
        for (DocumentChange change : documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
            switch (change.getType()) {
                case ADDED:
                    onDocumentAdded(change);
                    break;
                case MODIFIED:
                    onDocumentModified(change);
                    break;
                case REMOVED:
                    onDocumentRemoved(change);
                    break;
            }
        }

        onDataChanged();
    }

    public void startListening() {
        if (mQuery != null && mRegistration == null) {
            mRegistration = mQuery.addSnapshotListener(this);
        }
    }

    public void stopListening() {
        if (mRegistration != null) {
            mRegistration.remove();
            mRegistration = null;
        }

        mSnapshots.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void setQuery(Query query) {
        // Stop listening
        stopListening();

        // Clear existing data
        mSnapshots.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();

        // Listen to new query
        mQuery = query;
        startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mSnapshots.size();
    }

    public DocumentSnapshot getSnapshot(int index) {
        return mSnapshots.get(index);
    }

    protected void onDocumentAdded(DocumentChange change) {
        mSnapshots.add(change.getNewIndex(), change.getDocument());
        notifyItemInserted(change.getNewIndex());
    }

    protected void onDocumentModified(DocumentChange change) {
        if (change.getOldIndex() == change.getNewIndex()) {
            // Item changed but remained in same position
            mSnapshots.set(change.getOldIndex(), change.getDocument());
            notifyItemChanged(change.getOldIndex());
        } else {
            // Item changed and changed position
            mSnapshots.remove(change.getOldIndex());
            mSnapshots.add(change.getNewIndex(), change.getDocument());
            notifyItemMoved(change.getOldIndex(), change.getNewIndex());
        }
    }

    protected void onDocumentRemoved(DocumentChange change) {
        mSnapshots.remove(change.getOldIndex());
        notifyItemRemoved(change.getOldIndex());
    }

    protected void onError(FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

    }

    protected void onDataChanged() {
        setQuery(mQuery);
    }
}
```

A base Firestore adapter for querying:

CustomRecycler adapter:

```
    public class Bidhaa_Recycler_Adapter extends FirestoreAdapter{

    private static final int BIDHAA_VIEW_TYPE = 0;

    private static final int NATIVE_EXPRESS_AD_VIEW_TYPE = 1;

    public Bidhaa_Recycler_Adapter(Query query) {
        super(query);
        setQuery(query);
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        switch (viewType){

            case NATIVE_EXPRESS_AD_VIEW_TYPE:
                View native_Ad_View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.native_express_ad_container, parent, false);
                return new Native_Ad_ViewHolder(native_Ad_View);

            case BIDHAA_VIEW_TYPE:
                default:

                    View bidhaa_View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                            .inflate(R.layout.bidhaa_layout, parent, false);
                    return new Bidhaa_Holder(bidhaa_View);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        int itemViewType = getItemViewType(position);

        switch (itemViewType){

            case NATIVE_EXPRESS_AD_VIEW_TYPE:

                Native_Ad_ViewHolder nativeExpressHolder = (Native_Ad_ViewHolder) holder;
                NativeExpressAdView adView = (NativeExpressAdView) mSnapshots.get(position);
                ViewGroup adCardView = (ViewGroup) nativeExpressHolder.itemView;
                adCardView.removeAllViews();

                if (adView.getParent() != null){
                    ((ViewGroup) adView.getParent()).removeView(adView);
                }

                adCardView.addView(adView);
                break;

            case BIDHAA_VIEW_TYPE:
                default:
                    Bidhaa_Holder bidhaaHolder = (Bidhaa_Holder) holder;
                    //Bidhaa_Data bidhaaData = (Bidhaa_Data) mSnapshots.get(position);
                    bidhaaHolder.BindData(getSnapshot(itemViewType));
                    //((Bidhaa_Holder) holder).BindData(getSnapshot(position));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mSnapshots.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return (position % 2 == 0) ? NATIVE_EXPRESS_AD_VIEW_TYPE : BIDHAA_VIEW_TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(Object o, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
    }
}
```

First View Holder

`Bidhaa` ViewHolder:

```
class Bidhaa_Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

private ImageView picha;
private CircularProgressBar testing;
private TextView bidhaa, bei, muuzaji, namba;

public Context pichaContext;

Bidhaa_Holder(View bidhaa_view) {
    super(bidhaa_view);

    picha = bidhaa_view.findViewById(R.id.picha_bidhaa);
    bidhaa = bidhaa_view.findViewById(R.id.maelezo_bidhaa);
    bei = bidhaa_view.findViewById(R.id.bei_bidhaa);
    muuzaji = bidhaa_view.findViewById(R.id.muuzaji_bidhaa);
    namba = bidhaa_view.findViewById(R.id.simu_bidhaa);

    testing= bidhaa_view.findViewById(R.id.tester);
}

public void BindData(DocumentSnapshot docSnapshot) {

    Bidhaa_Data bidhaaData = docSnapshot.toObject(Bidhaa_Data.class);

    pichaContext = itemView.getContext();

    namba.setText(bidhaaData.getSimu());
    muuzaji.setText(bidhaaData.getMuuzaji());
    bidhaa.setText(bidhaaData.getBidhaa());
    bei.setText(bidhaaData.getBei());
    testing.progressiveStop();

    String Url = bidhaaData.getPicha();
    Picasso.with(pichaContext)
            .load(Url)
            .centerInside()
            .fit()
            .into(picha, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    testing.progressiveStop();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {
                    testing.progressiveStop();
                }
            });
```

My main activity:

```
    public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private Bidhaa_Recycler_Adapter bidhaaRecyclerAdapter;

    FirebaseFirestore firestoreBidhaa;
    SmoothProgressBar loading_Progress;

    List <Object> objectList = new ArrayList<>();

    static {
        FirebaseFirestore.setLoggingEnabled(true);
    }

    public static final int ITEMS_PER_AD = 2;
    private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "************";
    private static final String TAG = "Bidhaa_Activity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        firestoreBidhaa = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
                .setPersistenceEnabled(true)
                .build();

        firestoreBidhaa.setFirestoreSettings(settings);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.bidhaa_Recycler);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));

        loading_Progress = findViewById(R.id.progress);
        loading_Progress.applyStyle(R.style.PocketProgressBar);
        loading_Progress.progressiveStop();

        CollectionReference bidhaaCollection = firestoreBidhaa.collection("BIDHAA");//.orderBy("Muuzaji");
        Query query = bidhaaCollection.orderBy("Muuzaji");

        bidhaaRecyclerAdapter = new Bidhaa_Recycler_Adapter(query) {
            @Override
            protected void onDataChanged() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Data Change");
                recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
                loading_Progress.progressiveStop();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onError(FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                handleFirebaseException(e);
            }
        };

        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new Bidhaa_Recycler_Adapter(query));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(bidhaaRecyclerAdapter);

        addNativeExpressAds();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (bidhaaRecyclerAdapter != null) {
                bidhaaRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
            }
    }

    private void addNativeExpressAds() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= objectList.size(); i += ITEMS_PER_AD) {
            NativeExpressAdView adView = new NativeExpressAdView(Main.this);
            adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
            objectList.add(i, adView);
        }

        recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final float density = Main.this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

                AdSize adSize = new AdSize((int)(recyclerView.getWidth() / density), 150);
                for (int i = 0; i <=objectList.size(); i += 2){

                    NativeExpressAdView adViewSize = (NativeExpressAdView) objectList.get(i);
                    adViewSize.setAdSize(adSize);
                    adViewSize.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        bidhaaRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
        loading_Progress.progressiveStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        bidhaaRecyclerAdapter.stopListening();
        loading_Progress.progressiveStop();
    }

    private void handleFirebaseException(FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

        if (e.getCode() == FirebaseFirestoreException.Code.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            loading_Progress.progressiveStop();

            Alerter.create(this)
                    .enableSwipeToDismiss()
                    .setText("Permission Denied")
                    .setTitle("Error")
                    .show();
        }
    }
}
```

A native ad holder:

```
 package com.ngara_k.bidhaa;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
/**
 * Created by Ngara-K on 11/2/2017.
 */
class Native_Ad_ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public Native_Ad_ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}
```

Here is my logcat:

```
11-02 16:34:31.532 19435-19450/com.ngara_k.bidhaa I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeep]: Starting transaction: Apply remote event
11-02 16:34:31.542 19435-19450/com.ngara_k.bidhaa I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzejk]: (4a7ea5f4) Stream received: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzepe@33e4dc84
11-02 16:34:31.542 19435-19450/com.ngara_k.bidhaa I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeep]: Starting transaction: Apply remote event
11-02 16:35:23.091 19435-19435/com.ngara_k.bidhaa I/Ads: Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
11-02 16:35:23.091 19435-19435/com.ngara_k.bidhaa I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
11-02 16:35:31.601 19435-19450/com.ngara_k.bidhaa I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzejk]: (4a7ea5f4) Stream received: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzepe@da43d34f
11-02 16:35:31.601 19435-19450/com.ngara_k.bidhaa I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeep]: Starting transaction: Apply remote event
11-02 16:36:23.110 19435-19435/com.ngara_k.bidhaa I/Ads: Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
11-02 16:36:23.110 19435-19435/com.ngara_k.bidhaa I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
11-02 16:36:31.740 19435-19450/com.ngara_k.bidhaa I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzejk]: (4a7ea5f4) Stream received: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzepe@65567c39
11-02 16:36:31.740 19435-19450/com.ngara_k.bidhaa I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeep]: Starting transaction: Apply remote event
11-02 16:37:23.120 19435-19435/com.ngara_k.bidhaa I/Ads: Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
11-02 16:37:23.120 19435-19435/com.ngara_k.bidhaa I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
11-02 16:37:31.709 19435-19450/com.ngara_k.bidhaa I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzejk]: (4a7ea5f4) Stream received: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzepe@f499aecf
11-02 16:37:31.709 19435-19450/com.ngara_k.bidhaa I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeep]: Starting transaction: Apply remote event
11-02 16:38:23.129 19435-19435/com.ngara_k.bidhaa I/Ads: Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
11-02 16:38:23.129 19435-19435/com.ngara_k.bidhaa I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
11-02 16:38:31.829 19435-19450/com.ngara_k.bidhaa I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzejk]: (4a7ea5f4) Stream received: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzepe@d1555759
11-02 16:38:31.829 19435-19450/com.ngara_k.bidhaa I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeep]: Starting transaction: Apply remote event
11-02 16:39:23.128 19435-19435/com.ngara_k.bidhaa I/Ads: Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
11-02 16:39:23.128 19435-19435/com.ngara_k.bidhaa I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
11-02 16:39:31.418 19435-19450/com.ngara_k.bidhaa I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzejk]: (4a7ea5f4) Stream closed with status: zzcq{code=INTERNAL, description=Received unexpected EOS on DATA frame from server., cause=null}.
11-02 16:39:31.418 19435-19450/com.ngara_k.bidhaa I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzejk]: (4a7ea5f4) Stream sending: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzepc@9820cb7d
11-02 16:39:31.418 19435-19435/com.ngara_k.bidhaa I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzebn]: Firebase Auth is not available, getToken is returning no token.
11-02 16:39:31.418 19435-19450/com.ngara_k.bidhaa I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [FirestoreCallCredentials]: Successfully fetched token.
11-02 16:39:31.418 19435-19450/com.ngara_k.bidhaa I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzejk]: (4a7ea5f4) Stream is ready
11-02 16:39:33.348 19435-19450/com.ngara_k.bidhaa I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzejk]: (4a7ea5f4) Stream received headers: {date=Thu, 02 Nov 2017 13:39:34 GMT}
11-02 16:39:33.348 19435-19450/com.ngara_k.bidhaa I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzejk]: (4a7ea5f4) Stream received: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzepe@72b77077
11-02 16:39:33.348 19435-19450/com.ngara_k.bidhaa I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzejk]: (4a7ea5f4) Stream received: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzepe@c415b40d
11-02 16:39:33.478 19435-19450/com.ngara_k.bidhaa I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzejk]: (4a7ea5f4) Stream received: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzepe@1a60a68
11-02 16:39:33.478 19435-19450/com.ngara_k.bidhaa I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzejk]: (4a7ea5f4) Stream received: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzepe@aa6fb0f7
11-02 16:39:33.478 19435-19450/com.ngara_k.bidhaa I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzejk]: (4a7ea5f4) Stream received: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzepe@117ebd5c
11-02 16:39:33.478 19435-19450/com.ngara_k.bidhaa I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeep]: Starting transaction: Apply remote event
11-02 16:39:33.488 19435-19450/com.ngara_k.bidhaa I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzejk]: (4a7ea5f4) Stream received: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzepe@f4f6907d
11-02 16:39:33.488 19435-19450/com.ngara_k.bidhaa I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeep]: Starting transaction: Apply remote event
11-02 16:40:23.127 19435-19435/com.ngara_k.bidhaa I/Ads: Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
11-02 16:40:23.127 19435-19435/com.ngara_k.bidhaa I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
11-02 16:40:33.537 19435-19450/com.ngara_k.bidhaa I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzejk]: (4a7ea5f4) Stream received: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzepe@9cd50d7a
11-02 16:40:33.547 19435-19450/com.ngara_k.bidhaa I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeep]: Starting transaction: Apply remote event
11-02 16:41:23.127 19435-19435/com.ngara_k.bidhaa I/Ads: Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
11-02 16:41:23.127 19435-19435/com.ngara_k.bidhaa I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
11-02 16:41:33.586 19435-19450/com.ngara_k.bidhaa I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzejk]: (4a7ea5f4) Stream received: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzepe@721bf245
11-02 16:41:33.586 19435-19450/com.ngara_k.bidhaa I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeep]: Starting transaction: Apply remote event
11-02 16:42:23.126 19435-19435/com.ngara_k.bidhaa I/Ads: Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
11-02 16:42:23.126 19435-19435/com.ngara_k.bidhaa I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
11-02 16:42:33.736 19435-19450/com.ngara_k.bidhaa I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzejk]: (4a7ea5f4) Stream received: # com.google.android.gms.internal.zzepe@1d4d8242
11-02 16:42:33.736 19435-19450/com.ngara_k.bidhaa I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzeep]: Starting transaction: Apply remote event
```

Comment: can u show your database structure

Comment: For future visitors, you can take a look **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49277797/how-to-display-data-from-firestore-in-a-recyclerview-with-android/49277842)**, where I have explained step by step how to display data from Firestore into a `RecyclerView` using Android.